# RunJettyRun plugin and hot swap

Tags: eclipse-plugin, runjettyrun

I am using Java 1.8.0_144, Eclipse (Oxygen) and RunJettyRun plugin  on Windows to test my web application. When I modify the Java code in a non-static method (not change to the method signature or adding a new method), the change does not get reflected unless I shut down and resart RunJettyRun. I did some configuration as shown below, but it was not working.

[image]

How can I see code change effective without shutting down RunJettyRun?

Comment: Obvious question, but I assume you have started jetty in "debug" mode?

Comment: Yes. I always start jetty in debug mode.